# Mult-vitamin with more than 100% of daily recommended amount?

Tags: labeling, overdose, guidelines, medication-directions, multi-vitamin

There are vitamins with 150% of Vit C or whatever (and sometimes even advertised with that as a plus!) If the vitamin contains more than 100% of the RDA, does it get averaged out over the week?

Comment: Could you try to reword the question so that it seems less like a personal medical question (how you take a multivitamin not being relevant to how nutrients are absorbed)?

Comment: This may depend on the type of the product - sustained release products don't release the whole dose at once (but they don't release the substances over a week either). It also depends on the substance that crosses the RDA threshold and whether it is a hydrosoluble or a liposoluble one. We do need more detail to answer. You can always [edit] your question to add some. Thanks!